# Migration of .NET COM object to 64 bit

Tags: .net, c++, com-interop, 32bit-64bit

We have C++ application which uses several COM object. COM object are .NET based (using COM Interop).

I need to migrate application to 64 bit. I specifically need C++ application to be 64 bit. I don't want to recompile all of .NET com object to 64 bit and deliver two sets of DLL's (32 bit and 64 bit).

I was investigating and found that I can load 32 bit COM Dll's in 32 bit surrogate process using (DllSurrogate in registry). I know how to do that, but it means that all COM objects will become out of process.

In the C++ I had the code:
CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SomeClass, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_SomeInterface, (void**)&pobj);

It worked fine, but as soon as I switch to CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER (and add registry keys for DllSurrogate), it can't find interfaces (error 0x80004002). I checked registry and found out that when .NET COM DLL is registered, it adds ClsID registry keys, but doesn't add Interface and TypeLib registry key.

The question is, how to create these registry keys for .NET COM?

Regards,
Victor

Comment: Your attempting to only support x64 bit operating for what reason exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If you want everything in-process then both the application and the COM object must be in 64-bit. See [Can I load a 32 bit DLL into a 64 bit process on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225151/can-i-load-a-32-bit-dll-into-a-64-bit-process-on-windows).