# Can I link a 32-bit native dll (not .Net assembly) into my 64 bit .Net applicaiton?

Tags: .net, winapi, 32bit-64bit

We have an old 3rd party component which is a 32 bit native dll. In our COM based app, we link it through Windows API. Now, we are planning to upgrade our app to .Net and running on 64 bit system. My question: Can we still link the old 32 bit native dll into our 64 bit .net app through Windows API? If not, any ideas on how to get it to work?

Comment: 32-bit native code works fine on a 64-bit machine.  You'll have to keep the EXE project's Platform target setting at x86.

Comment: 32-bit code works on a 64-bit machine only if the WOW64 emulator is installed. Starting with Win2K8 R2, WOW64 is now an optional component, so it may or may not be installed.

Comment: Nobody in their right mind is going to omit WOW64

Comment: *Not in their right mind* pretty accurately describes an insanely large amount of customers. Being an optional component you cannot simply ignore the possibility.

Comment: Except for people who don't need to run 32-bit apps. WOW64 was made optional for a reason. Microsoft would not waste time making a 64bit-only SKU unless people would actually use it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I load a 32 bit DLL into a 64 bit process on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225151/can-i-load-a-32-bit-dll-into-a-64-bit-process-on-windows)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

32-bit code cannot be used inside of a 64-bit process, period.  However, you can wrap the 32-bit DLL inside of a 32-bit out-of-process COM server (if the DLL is already a COM server, then you can use a COM [DllSurrogate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms691260.aspx) to proxy it), then any 64-bit process (.NET or otherwise) can use that COM server as needed.  Otherwise, you will have to set the .NET project to 32-bit instead of 64-bit.  It will still run on a 64-bit machine, provided the WOW64 emulator component is installed.

Comment: Thanks Remy for the input. Just want to clarify, when you say wrap it inside of a 32-bit out-of-process COM server, that's still a 32-bit COM dll, right? Will 64-bit .net app be able to link to this 32-bit component? Through .Net Interop?

Comment: No, an out-of-process COM server is an EXE, not a DLL. It runs in its own process, and COM marshals calls over process boundaries as needed. That is what allows a 32-bit out-of-process COM server to be accessed by a 64-bit client process (and vice versa for a 64-bit server and 32-bit client). A .NET client app would use normal COM interop regardless of whether the COM server is in-process or out-of-process, since those details are hidden by COM.

Comment: A client of ours claims that their developers are able to have their .net app (compiled as x64) invoke a 32-bit windows native dll using Windows API just as they did with their 32-bit app (.net app compiled as x86). They ask why it won't work for us if it works for them. That doesn't sound right to me at all and I didn't find anything in my research that supports that. But before I tell them that I don't belive what they said, I still want to make sure that I am not missing any possibilities. Can what they said be possible?

Comment: It is physically impossible to load a 32bit DLL into a 64bit process, and to execute 32bit code directly in a 64bit process. Period. I don't know what they are doing, but it is not direct. There has to be some layer in between.

Comment: What they say they are doing is having their .net app compiled under "Any CPU" option. And that's how they made it work. I just tried the same and, to my suprise, it seems to work too! According to some explaination I found about Any CPU:"On a 64-bit machine: •Any CPU: runs as a 64-bit process, can load Any CPU and x64 assemblies, will get BadImageFormatException if it tries to load an x86 assembly." It looks like the app is still a 64 bit app (because we are testing on a 64 bit machine). What magic does this thing do to make a 64 bit .net app work with a 32bit native dll though?

Comment: An "Any CPU" app will run as a 64bit process on a 64bit OS. It **cannot** load 32bit DLLs so either the app is actually running as a 32bit process (use TaskManager to verify), or else .NET is delegating the DLL access to a separate 32bit surrogate process.

Comment: 64bit version of Windows contains both 64bit versions and 32bit versions of DLLs, that is probably how they say that they can do it. They think they are loading 32bit windows DLL into 64bit process, but they actually load the 64bit versions. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384274%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Short answer Link is not possible because you can't link 32 and 64 bit together
Communicate yes, but you need two executable one 32bits and one 64bits
Then after you need to search for interprocess communication. 
If you go to message communication, the only one you could send between 32 as 64bits is `WM_COPYDATA` and it could be block by `UIPI` so you may need to use the `ChangeWindowMessageFilter` to let it through.
It works but you'll need to encapsulate every call you want to make between the 32 and 64 system.