# Why can't a 64-bit process use 32-bit dlls?

Tags: windows, winapi, dll, 32bit-64bit

In this post, I'm talking about native windows applications and DLLs created with C++ and Win32 API.

From the post [Can I load a 32 bit DLL into a 64 bit process on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225151/can-i-load-a-32-bit-dll-into-a-64-bit-process-on-windows) I understand that 64-bit process cannot use 32-bit DLLs directly. One way to get around this is to host the DLL in a 32-bit process and use some form of IPC. 
This being the case, what is the reason behind this? ***Why* can't 64-bit process use 32-bit DLLs?**
Could it be the differences between the x86 and x64 instruction sets?

Comment: The question seems not to be duplicate; none of the answers in the "duplicate" question provide an answer for THIS question: The "duplicate" question asks IF it is possible (the answers say "no") while THIS question is about the REASON why! @John: Please ASK YOUR QUESTION AGAIN; your question should contain a reference to the other question (like "the answers of the question 'Can I load a 32 bit DLL...' say that it is not possible. What is the reason for this?") so everyone can see that your question is not exactly the same.

Comment: @Ben Voigt the post you suggested does not answer my question. My question is reason why 64-bit process cannot use 32-bit dll?

Comment: Well, my comment highlighting the dupe seems to have disappeared.  But the *answers* to that other question most certainly answer this one as well.  Specifically, click through the [link to the Raymond Chen blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/10/20/9006720.aspx) and read it.

Answer (score 0):

If an address passed to 32-bit code had any bit higher than 32nd set it would be lost due to pointer size mismatch and would most likely result in an AV.

Comment: 64-bit processes are limited to 32-bit address values unless otherwise flagged in the module. So this can be mitigated.